# If every absolutely convergent series is convergent in $X$, then $X$ is a Banach space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

Here is my try..

By hypothesis, the convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\|x_n\|$ in $\mathbb{R}$ $\implies$ the convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_n$ in $X$.

Pick a Cauchy sequence $\{ f_n\}$ in $X$. Then $\forall$  $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ $n>m>N$ s.t $\|f_n - f_m \|< \epsilon$.

and   $| \|f_n\| - \|f_m\| | \leq \|f_n - f_m \|< \epsilon$ that is $\{\|f_n\|\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ thus it converges in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence it is bounded (i.e. $\exists k>0$ s.t |  \|$f_n$\|  | $\leq k$,  $\forall$ $n=1,2,..$).

$\implies S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\|f_n\| \leq nk$ but also the sequence $\{S_n\}$ is monotonically increasing thus $\{S_n\}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ $\implies \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_n$ converges in $X$ by hypothesis thus the sequence $f_n \rightarrow 0$ in $X$. Thus $X$ is a Banach space.

Comment: Take a look at the definition of boundedness and then maybe reconsider your assertion that $S_n$ is bounded. ;)

Comment: Oh yes, $S_n$ can't be bounded as the set of natural numbers is not bounded above. Thank you!

Comment: If you type \|f\| instead of ||f|| it looks like $\|f\|$ instead of $||f||$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  a subsequence of  a Cauchy sequenec converges, so does the entire sequence. Choose  subsequence $f_{n_k}$ such that $\|f_{n_k}-f_{n_{k+1}}\| < \frac 1 {2^{k}}$. Then $\sum_k (f_{n_k}-f_{n_{k+1}})$ converges absolutely and hence it converges. By writing down the partial sums show that $\lim_k f_{n_k}$ exists. This proves convergence of $\{f_{n_k}\}$ hence that of $(f_n)$.